# Как заменить PowerShell в контекстном меню на командную строку?

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль, powershell, командная-строка

Переустановил Windows и пропала командная строка из контекстного меню.
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Button</kbd> тоже ничего не дает, там только PowerShell, как его заменить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо ОГОМНЕЙШЕЕ, все сработало отлично! Достал этот ПоверШелл

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1) Добавление `cmd` в контекстное меню** (оригинальная [cтатья](http://remontka.pro/open-command-window-windows-10/))

1. Нажмите клавиши <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> и введите `regedit` для запуска редактора реестра.
2. Перейдите к разделу реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directrory\shell\cmd`, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по имени раздела и выберите пункт меню `«Разрешения»`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. В следующем окне нажмите кнопку <kbd>Дополнительно</kbd>.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Нажмите <kbd>Изменить</kbd> рядом с пунктом `«Владелец»`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. В поле `«Введите имена выбираемых объектов»` введите имя вашего пользователя и нажмите <kbd>Проверить имена</kbd>, а затем — <kbd>Ок</kbd>. Примечание: если используется учетная запись `Майкрософт`, введите адрес электронной почты вместо имени пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. Отметьте пункт `«Заменить владельца подконтейнеров и объектов»` и `«Заменить все записи разрешений дочернего объекта»`, затем нажмите <kbd>Ок</kbd> и подтвердите действие.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. Вы вернетесь в окно параметров безопасности раздела реестра, в нем выберите пункт `«Администраторы»` и установите отметку `«Полный доступ»`, нажмите <kbd>Ок</kbd>.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

8. Вернувшись в редактор реестра, нажмите по значению `HideBasedOnVelocityId` (в правой части редактора реестра) правой кнопкой мыши и выберите пункт `«Удалить»`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9. Повторите шаги `2-8` для разделов `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directrory\Background\ shell\cmd` и `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd`

Результат при <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd>`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2) Замена `PowerShell` в <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> меню**

1. Откройте контекстное меню на панели задач и выберите пункт `Параметры панели задач`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. В появившемся меню отключите пункт `Заменить командную строку оболочкой Windows PowerShell...`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат при <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо очень помогло, облазил много разных советов, но этот рабочий!